# Sorting questions by user

Tags: discussion, soft-question

Is there a way to see the questions where particular users (I choose) participate?

(I guess this should be in meta, but I don't know how to post it there)

Comment: You can always ask in chat.

Comment: You need $5$ reputation points to participate in meta (except the network meta that is called meta.stackoverflow). You can search e.g. `user:117153` to search for posts user 117153 participated in (since that's you, a `user:me` would work too for you).

Comment: @user4140 Chat is only available to those with at least 20 reputation.

Answer (score 1):

You can either visit your [profile](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/117153/user117153) or go to [search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search) and type in `user:me`

The results will look like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:me).

Comment: I'm not really trying to search questions, I'd like to _follow_ the activity of specific users. Do you know if that's possible? Thanks. :)

Comment: @user117153: you can click on a user's name on any post and see their profile. If you record their user number, you won't have to find a post in the future. You can also search for them on the user page